# Google API WebRequest not working

Tags: c#, google-api, httpwebrequest, webrequest

My request isn't working correctly.  I have a search box with a search button.  Users can enter an address in the search box and then the address is sent out Google's API.  But this isn't working for some reason.  Does anyone know why?  I will also include a pic of what the value of `request` is when debugging.

```
private void RequestResponseHandler(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    Stream responseStream = null;
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
        responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that there's something wrong with this request? What is the expected and what is the actual result you are getting? Also it would be better for you not to expose your API keys to the public.

Comment: Well when debugging those three exceptions are there for `response` and then it goes into `RequestResponseHandler` and breaks on `response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);`.  I can also share a pic of that as well.

Comment: Those exceptions are perfectly normal. See my answer for the real issue with your code.

Comment: You say it breaks on "response =...". You mean it throws an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: I added a pic to show the exception that it gives.  It then enters the catch clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The geocode API returns JSON. Example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=fifth%20avenue&key=AIzaSyCgsNpuUoH7m6U7lqeZjlLZ3MgM15PW15o</strike>

But here you are trying to put this JSON into an XML document:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
```

I would recommend you using a JSON parser instead.

Now that you have shown the actual exception it seems that in the environment in which you are working (Silverlight?) you don't have permission to access cross domain resources:

[image]

You are getting a `Security Error` because of this. Depending on the actual environment you are working with there might be different ways to resolve this issue. For example in Silverlight you might need to [include a `clientaccesspolicy.xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(VS.95).aspx) file in order to make cross domain calls. In this file you need to explicitly allow the domains to which you need to make HTTP requests (in your case that would be `maps.googleapis.com`).

Comment: I can just change 'json' to xml in the example uri.  But that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I see, when you say that it breaks on the `request.EndGetResponse` line, what is the exact exception being thrown? Does it enter the `catch` clause?

Comment: I added another pic... it hits that first line and then enters the catch clause.

Comment: So it throws 'System.NotSupportedException'.

Comment: Could you please inspect the `ex` object in the `catch` clause - this is where the real exception is? In your second screenshot you have inspected the `asyncResult` variable which is of very little interest for the purpose of debugging this issue.

Comment: Ohhh, I see now: Inner Exception: `Security Error`

Comment: Yes I see that as well, but don't know why it is occurring.

Comment: It's occurring because you seem to be doing some cross domain requests. What kind of application is this? Is it a Silverlight application?

Comment: If you are using Silverlight you need a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` in order to make cross domain calls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Would I still need that even if I decided to go with json?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the response format. It's a security feature in Silverlight. It's exactly the same as with AJAX. In order to make cross domain HTTP requests you need an explicit policy for that. Just the mechanisms are different between javascript and Silverlight but it is the same security concept built into both platforms. Think of the browser as a sandboxed environment and when you try to cross those boundaries you need to explicitly state this in a policy.